# Change @RenderBody() target via links?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Probably not going about this correctly, but I have an ASP page using Razor and I'm trying to figure out how I can make it so when a user clicks a link in my navigation bar it only changes the main section... I've tried using  helpers with the target="mainSection" parameter, but it gives me an error on the  Click but that just gives me a runtime error saying " Cannot find '/' application"

Probly missing something stupid...

my _Layout:

```
<div id="content">
        <!-- BANNER -->
        <div id="banner">
            @RenderSection("Banner")
        </div>
        <!-- NAVIGATION -->
        <div id="navigation">
         @RenderSection("Navigation")
        </div>
        <!-- MAIN DISPLAY -->
        <div id="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <!-- FOOTER -->
        <div id="footer">
            @RenderSection("Footer")
        </div>
```

I just want to change the "main" div to whatever page cooresponds with whatever link is clicked.

Comment: Then you need to set up the contents of your renderbody as a partial view, create a method in the controller that would return this partial view, and have an ajax link on the page that would update the div by calling this controller method. It has nothing to do with sections.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more?  I get the just of what you're saying, I imagine in the renderbody I'd put @html.partial(methodToGetView) but how might I setup and call the method to return the view?

Comment: Have you done any research on what/how [Single Page Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) work?  It's even a template you can using VS 2013.

Comment: You need to read up on using the Ajax helpers.